# APC loads on apache fine but data isn't saved

Tags: php, apache, nginx, apc

I installed APC 3.1.5 beta because 3.0.19 gives me some weird error.

3.1.5 is installed fine, it appears on phpinfo and functions work without errors. The only problem is that data is not saved persistantly.

I can do apc_store and apc_fetch inside the same script and on the same instance it will return the stored data fine, but if i use two instance where one stores and the other fetches, the later won't return anything, just like the key doesn't exist.

Also using the apc.php provided i got the following info that may help:

```
Shared Memory   1 Segment(s) with 32.0 MBytes
(mmap memory, pthread mutex locking) 
Uptime  0 minutes

Runtime Settings
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  /tmp/apc.rSmNYe
apc.num_files_hint  1024
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    32M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 0
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    0
apc.write_lock  1
```

Installed using pecl on
Apache 2.0.63, PHP 5.3.3, nginx 0.8.46, CentOS 5 64bit

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Zend Optimizer module is not loaded